# Работа с бинарными файлами и структурами

Tags: c++, файлы

Ввожу элементы структуры и записываю в файл. Потом нужно вывести данные в таблице.

```
...----------------------------...
...|tip.avto[8]|tip.garaga[13]|...
...----------------------------...
```

Но переменная `tip.avto[8]` выводится на экран сразу с переменной `tip.garaga[13]`, затем отдельно выводиться переменная `tip.garaga[13]`.

```
...----------------------------...
...|tip.avto[8]+tip.garaga[13]|tip.garaga[13]|...
...----------------------------...
```

Без понятия что делать

```
struct vvod
{
char fio[24];
int srok;
char tip_avto[8];
char tiv_garaga[13];
int nomer;
string znak;
};

int main()
{

SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
const char * kat_avto_l = "Легковая";
const char * kat_avto_g = "Грузовая";
const char * kat_garaga_m = "Металлический";
const char * kat_garaga_k = "Кирпичный";
FILE * kar;
vvod mas[6];
int b, z, z_v, m, m_1;

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{

    kar = fopen("kar.bin", "wb");
    cout << "ФИО арендатора\nВаш выбор:";
    gets_s(mas[i].fio);
    system("cls");
    cout << "Срок аренды гаража:\nВаш выбор:";
    cin >> mas[i].srok;
    system("cls");
m:
    system("cls");
    cout << "Тип авто:\n1.Легковая.\n2.Грузовая.";
    cout<<"\nВаш выбор : ";
    cin >> b;
    switch (b)
    {
    case 1:
        strcpy(mas[i].tip_avto, kat_avto_l);
        break;
    case 2:
        strcpy(mas[i].tip_avto, kat_avto_g);
        break;
    default:    goto m;
    }
    system("cls");

m_1:
    system("cls");
    cout << "Тип гаража:\n1.Металлический.\n2.Кирпичный.\nВаш выбор:";
    cin >> z;
    switch (z)
    {
    case 1:
        strcpy(mas[i].tiv_garaga, kat_garaga_m);
        z_v = mas[i].srok * 2500;
        break;
    case 2:
        strcpy(mas[i].tiv_garaga, kat_garaga_k);
        z_v = mas[i].srok * 5000;
        break;
    default:    goto m_1;
    }
    system("cls");
    cout << "Место гаража (1-99):\nВаш выбор:";
    cin >> mas[i].nomer;
    system("cls");
    getchar();
    cout << "Регистрационный автомобильный знак:\nВаш выбор:";
    cin >> mas[i].znak;
    system("cls");
    cout << "Анкета заполненна:)";
    fwrite(&mas[i], sizeof(mas[i]), 1, kar);

}

kar = fopen("kar.bin", "rb");
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    fread(&mas[i], sizeof(mas[i]), 1, kar);
    cout << "Данные с файла:\n\n";
    cout << "Знак:" << mas[i].znak;
    cout << "Тип авто:"<<mas[i].tip_avto;
    cout << "=======================================================================================================================\n";
    cout << "|"<< mas[i].fio << "|" << mas[i].srok << "|" << mas[i].tip_avto << "|" << mas[i].tiv_garaga << "|" << mas[i].nomer << "|" << mas[i].znak << "|";
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: А Вы на чем пишите? на с++ или си? все Ваши `char*` можно почти спокойно заменить на `std::string`. Но запись в файл в этом случае нужно делать аккуратно. Вы применили подобное для znak и в этом случае строка `fwrite(&mas[i], sizeof(mas[i]), 1, kar);` пишет немного не то, что Вы ожидаете.

Comment: Пишу на с++ 
Можно более подробнее описать?

Answer (score 2):

Тип `"Легковая"` это `char[9]` (подразумевая cp1251 кодировку), а не `char[8]`  это значит, что `tip_avto` слишком маленький: нет места для нулевого байта в конце. Попробуйте объявить `char tip_avto[9]`, а не `char tip_avto[8]`.

Пример, который существенные моменты для проблемы из вашего кода повторяет:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
  char a[3];
  char b[3];
};

int main()
{
  const char * too_long = "abc"; // const char[4]
  const char * has_zero = "de";  // const char[3]
  S s;
  std::strcpy(s.a, too_long);
  std::strcpy(s.b, has_zero);
  std::cout << "<<" << s.a << "|" << s.b << ">>\n";
}
```

Результат:

```
$ g++ *.cc && ./a.out
<<abcde|de>>
```

Видно, что `strcpy` записал за границы `s.a` (напечатано `ab|b`), поэтому второй strcpy затёр нулевой байт в конце `abc`, поэтому `std::cout << s.a` напечатало байты за границей `s.a`.

Достаточно `char a[3]` на `char a[4]` заменить, тогда результат становится:

```
$ g++ *.cc && ./a.out
<<abc|de>>
```

напечатано `a|b` как и положено.

---

В коде есть и другие проблемы, к примеру, пытаться просто так struct с `std::string` записать, аналогично записи указателя. См. [Serializing a class which contains a `std::string`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7046244/4279).

Comment: jfs, огромное спасибо